# Fastest Way of Transferring Values between data.frame(s) using Common ID Columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data.frame, and I want to assign the values of "custMeanPrice" in "d" data.frame with the corresponding values in "att.customer" data.frame by equal "customerID"

```
> head(d)
  customerID custMeanPrice
1        794             0
2        794             0
3        794             0
4        808             0
5        825             0
6        825             0
> dim(d)
[1] 428,165      2

> head(att.customer)
  customerID meanPrice
1        794  68.91000
2        808  39.90000
3        825  79.34444
4        850  76.18571
5        860  93.72353
6        873  69.90000
> dim(att.customer)
[1] 49,870     2
```

I tried to use following to handle it but it is very slow since the dimensions are big, and couldn't to see the end.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(att.customer)){
  k = which(d$customerID == att.customer$customerID[i])
  d$custMeanPrice[k] = att.customer$meanPrice[i]
}
```

What is the best way of doing this in a fast and smart manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)
setkey(setDT(att.customer), customerID)
att.customer[d][,custMeanPrice:=NULL][]
#   customerID meanPrice
#1:        794  68.91000
#2:        794  68.91000
#3:        794  68.91000
#4:        808  39.90000
#5:        825  79.34444
#6:        825  79.34444
```

From @David Arenburg's comments, the above could be also done without converting `att.customer` to `data.table`

```
setkey(setDT(d), customerID)[, custMeanPrice := as.numeric(custMeanPrice)]
d[att.customer, custMeanPrice := meanPrice][]
#    customerID custMeanPrice
#1:        794      68.91000
#2:        794      68.91000
#3:        794      68.91000
#4:        808      39.90000
#5:        825      79.34444
#6:        825      79.34444
```

Or if the `custMeanPrice` is already `numeric` class

```
 setkey(setDT(d), customerID)
 d[att.customer, custMeanPrice := meanPrice][]
```

Or you could use `match` from `base R`

```
d$custMeanPrice <- att.customer$meanPrice[match(d$customerID,
             att.customer$customerID)]

 d
 #  customerID custMeanPrice
#1        794      68.91000
#2        794      68.91000
#3        794      68.91000
#4        808      39.90000
#5        825      79.34444
#6        825      79.34444
```

#### data

```
d <-  structure(list(customerID = c(794L, 794L, 794L, 808L, 825L, 825L
), custMeanPrice = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("customerID", 
"custMeanPrice"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6"))

att.customer <-   structure(list(customerID = c(794L, 808L, 825L, 850L, 860L, 873L
), meanPrice = c(68.91, 39.9, 79.34444, 76.18571, 93.72353, 69.9
 )), .Names = c("customerID", "meanPrice"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Thanks! "match" function works so fast that I am impressed! It tooks only a second to finish all of the 428165 rows althoug the for which combination tooks more than 40 minutes.. the data.table part gave me error but, is the code is correct?

Comment: @ykpemre Yes, the `match` is fast enough.  I tested the `data.table` with `IDs` in `d` that are not in `att.customer`.  It worked fine in the example.

Comment: it returned "Error in `:=`(custMeanPrice, NULL) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=")."
But I tried now again it didn't give any error and it is very successful too, thanks.

Comment: You can also skip converting `att.customer` to data.table by doing `setkey(setDT(d), customerID)[, custMeanPrice := as.numeric(custMeanPrice)];
d[att.customer, custMeanPrice := meanPrice][]`. Though if the OP will apriori set the column `custMeanPrice` correctly (while creating the data), simply `setkey(setDT(d), customerID);
d[att.customer, custMeanPrice := meanPrice][]` will suffice.